# Minted package prints backslash in red rectangle

Tags: minted

For example, I have the next document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    
    There is a function \mintinline[bgcolor=lightgray]{c}|printf()|. You can make a new line by passing \mintinline[bgcolor=lightgray]{c}|\n|
    
    \begin{minted}[autogobble, bgcolor=lightgray]{c++}
        int main() {
        printf("stuff and newline\n");
        printf("stuff in new line");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    \end{minted}
    
\end{document}
```

It typesets to:
[image]
So question is:

Why `\mintinline[bgcolor=lightgray]{c}|\n|` have produced that red box for backslash?

I have been serching in `minted` package documentation (by `texdoc minted`) and could not find a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pygments parses `\n` as a C syntax error (which it is with no context) you will see `\PYGerr` in the generated file.

Simplest would be to tell minted the `\n` is plain text not C, or just use `\verb`